# best way to iterate through list in C#

Tags: c#

let's say I had a list in this form

```
 x.y.z[]

 x.y.z[0].a.b = "123"
 x.y.z[1].a.b = "321"
 x.y.z[2].a.b = "567"
 x.y.z[3].a.b = "123"
 x.y.z[4].a.b = "321"
 x.y.z[5].a.b = "567"
```

and I just wanted to write a method that'd go through each z[] to check if their b element contains "123", what's the best way of approaching that?

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to write a loop? How to write a function? How to use LINQ?

Comment: Maybe it is an ad of the ?. operation? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your declarations are something like this:

```
private class X { public Y y;}
private class Y { public Z[] z;}
private class Z { public A a;}
private class A { public string b;}
```

In which case this will return all `z` for which the `a.b` value is `test` (e.g. your "123"):

```
public IEnumerable<Z> Just(string test)
{
    return x.y.z.Where(z => z.a.b == test);
}
```

Or this will simply say whether there are any which satisfy your test:

```
public bool Any(string test)
{
    return x.y.z.Any(z => z.a.b == test);
}
```

Or if there could be many and it's a large volume of data, but you only want one of them, then this might be what you want:

```
public Z First(string test)
{
    return x.y.z.First(z => z.a.b == test);
}
```

It actually makes a lot more assumptions than just the one I said, so would be unsafe to use without checking e.g. null values along the way.

Comment: cool. guess I can use a bool and .any() to get what I need. thanks.

Comment: Sure. Or `First` to get just the first instance, which might be what you want if there could be many. It depends on what you want, which is why you have to be clear in the question as to how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best example I can give with the limited information you've provided;

```
 if (x  != null && x.y != null && x.y.z != null)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < x.y.z.Length; i++)
     {
         if (x.y.z[i].a != null)
         {
             if (x.y.z[i].a.b == "123")
                 return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false; //return false by default since we'll break from the loop if  we ever find the element you're looking for
```